# Automatic Storage class

Tags: c, automatic-storage

> **Automatic** **Storage** used in a function does not re-initialize the **i** variable declared using the **auto** keyword.

> **Practice.c** **:** main() and func() are in the **Practice.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  func();
  func();
  func();
}


func()
{
  auto int i=1;
  printf("  i = %d",i);
  i=i+1;
}
```

After compilation when I execute **Practice.exe** the output is as follows :

```
i = 1
i = 1
i = 1
```

Every time **main()** calls **func()** i is re-initialized to 1. This is correct as scope of **i** is within the **func()** block, and when the control comes out of **this** block the value of **i** is lost. So, when I will be calling this **func()** function for the second time the value of **i** will be re-initialized to **1**.

Check the following **New.c** Program.

> **New.c** **:** contains both **main()** & **func()**

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  func();
  func();
  func();
  func();
  func();
  func();
  func();
  func();  
}


func()
{
  auto int i;
  printf("  i = %d",i);
  i=i+1;
}
```

> Just to be sure, I called the function **func()** 8 times.
>   But in **New.c,** **i** is not initialized. When I executed this program after compilation, the output of it is as follows :

```
i = 4201582
i = 4201583
i = 4201584
i = 4201585
i = 4201586
i = 4201587
i = 4201588
i = 4201589
```

> The output shows increment on every call. What is the exact reason behind this ?

Comment: You are learning from either a very old C text or a very outdated one. While the `auto` keyword still exists in C, it is basically never used.

Comment: @duskwuff May be you are right. I'm a beginner, with very little knowledge, so I started with what I have. But if you could provide the correct reason, that would really help.

Answer (score 1):

> The output shows increment on every call. What is the exact reason
>   behind this ?

Variables with automatic storage allocation are not initialized by default and **it is undefined behaviour to access an uninitialized variable**. This means the behaviour of your second program cannot be reasoned out.

Also, note that the default stororage class of variables in function scope is automatic. Therefore, you don't need the `auto` keyword to qualify the definition of `i`.

```
// in function scope

auto int i;
// equivalent to
int i;
```

Also, it's wrong to say

> So, when I will be calling this func() function for the second time
>   the value of i will be re-initialized to 1.

The variable `i` is not re-initialized. It goes out of scope once the function containing it returns. When the function is called again, it's again allocated on the stack. **This does not mean that it is allocated on the same memory address.**

Also, you need to take care of the return type and parameter list of the functions. The implicit return type is `int` and empty parameter list means no information is available about the number and type of arguments which means the function takes a fixed but unknown number of arguments of unknown type. You should always explicitly mention `void` in the parameter list to mean that the function takes no argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// prototype of the function func
void func(void);

// main should have one of the below signatures - 
// int main(void); or 
// int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
int main(void)
{
  func();
  func();
  func();
}

// explicitly mention void in the 
// parameter list to mean the function
// takes no argument
void func(void)
{
  // using auto keyword is redundant because 
  // local variables have automatic storage allocation
  int i = 1;
  printf("i = %d", i);
  i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: @user3591973 you are welcome :) Also, you need to take care of return type and parameter list of the functions. The implicit return type is `int` and empty parameter list means no information is available about the number and type of arguments which means the function takes a fixed but unknown number of arguments of unknown type. You should always explicitly mention `void` in the parameter list to mean that the function takes no argument.

Comment: **This does not mean that it is allocated on the same memory address.**

So you mean when for the first time I call **func()** than **i** is provided with a garbage value say i=12345 & stored at **22222** memory location, and when I call **func()** for the second time, the variable returns back to scope with the former garbage value & gets incremented & becomes **i = 12346** but uses a different memory location to store say **33333**. @ajay

Comment: @user3591973 yes, right. The next time you call `func`, `i` may be stored at memory location which is different than `22222` and may have a different garbage value - whatever bit pattern happens to be at that memory address.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, you make use of `i` without ever having initialized it.

The value is therefore undefined by the language.  The fact that you see a pattern of the value incrementing is an artifact of the particular compiler you are using.

In the first iteration, you have a random-seeming value that happens to be at the memory location that `i` represents.  Your function increments the value at that memory location, then that memory location happens to be used for subsequent calls.

Comment: So the value that is being displayed as the output, what is it? Is it a garbage value or the address of the memory that is named **i** ?
@Eric J.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The code `i=i+1` increments whatever garbage is at that location, then that same location happens to be reused on the next call.

Comment: So the garbage value gets incremented, whereas the memory location remains the same. And the value that is displayed in the output is the garbage value. Am I interpreting it correct ?

Comment: Yes. And the fact that the memory location remains the same, is by chance.